# NunitLite Custom ITestListener, TestOutput() never called

Tags: nunit

I have implemented a custom implementation of an NunitLite ITestListener.  The TestOutput(...) method is never called, regarless of which way I call stdout (Console.WriteLine, Trace.WriteLIne, Debug.WriteLine, etc.).  I'm not sure if this is a bug or not.  Simple code inspection shows the TestOutput class never being instantiated on captured output.  I greatly appreciate your thoughts any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this functionality is not supported by default with NUnitLite.  That being said, a simple redirect to standard IO with a custom TextWriter (see below for code) works great.  Huge thanks to Charlie Pool for the base answer.

In your program.cs or App.xaml.cs use the following:

```
//Override output in order to get mid-test output.
Console.SetOut(new TestListenerTextWriter(IoC.Resolve<ITestListener>(), TestOutputType.Out));
Console.SetError(new TestListenerTextWriter(IoC.Resolve<ITestListener>(), TestOutputType.Error));
Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(new TestListenerTextWriter(IoC.Resolve<ITestListener>(), TestOutputType.Trace)));
```

Then define the TestListenerTextWriter as follows.

```
public class TestListenerTextWriter : TextWriter
{
    private readonly ITestListener _eventListener;
    private readonly TestOutputType _type;

    public TestListenerTextWriter(ITestListener eventListener, TestOutputType type)
    {
        _eventListener = eventListener;
        _type = type;
    }
    override public void Write(char aChar)
    {
        _eventListener.TestOutput(new TestOutput(aChar.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), _type));
    }

    override public void Write(string aString)
    {
        _eventListener.TestOutput(new TestOutput(aString, _type));
    }

    override public void WriteLine(string aString)
    {
        _eventListener.TestOutput(new TestOutput(aString + NewLine, _type));
    }

    override public Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.Default; }
    }
}
```